# How to get a nested FormArray control in Angular 9 ReactiveForm

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

---

**EDIT**

The first part of the problem was solved thanks to the answer of Chellappan above, but i am encountering other problems, that made me do a stackblitz that can be found here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzh3dh

The problems are that i can't retrieve correctly the list of products selected from the form cause they are all outputed :

```
  "courses": [
    {
      "courseName": "Dessert",
      "products": [
        {
          "product": true
        },
        {
          "product": false
        },
        {
          "product": null
        }
      ]
```

I don't know how to be able to retrieve something like:

```
  "courses": [
    {
      "courseName": "Dessert",
      "products": [
        {
          "Crumble aux pommes": true
        },
        {
          "Mousse au chocolat maison": false
        },
        {
          "Riz au lait": false
        }
      ]
```

And the second problem is that the labels of my checkboxes are not independent. If i add a new 'course' and that i select some products, the labels of all checkboxes in other courses are changed too.

[image]

I hope that my post is not too messy, i don't edit messages so often on Stack Overflow

**END OF EDIT**

---

I have a reactive form with nested form Array to describe a menu that contains several courses
and each course contans several products, but i can't figure out how to make it works.
My actual problem is that i don't manage to retrieve my second level of controls.

Here is the json structure of the menu:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "price": "",
  "courses": [
    {
      "courseName": "",
      "products": [
        {
          "product": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I followed this project as an example :

[Deep nested reactive form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here is my simplified form for readability purpose :

```html
    <form [formGroup]="menuForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(menuForm)">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="name"
            type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
          <input
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="price"
            type="number">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" (click)="onAddCourse()">
          Add course
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="row" formArrayName="courses">
        <div *ngFor="let course of getCourses(menuForm); let i = index"
            [formGroupName]="i">

          <div class="...">
              <select
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="courseName">
                <option *ngFor="let course of courses">{{course.name}}</option>
              </select>

              <button type="button" class="mt-2 btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="onLoadProducts(i)">
                Load Products // <- will load products that have course Name selected form the input 'courseName'above
              </button>

              <div class="row" formArrayName="products">
                <div class="col-md-12"
                     *ngFor="let product of getProducts(menuForm); let j = index"
                      [formGroupName]="j">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="product{{i}}-{{j}}" 
                   formControlName="product"/>
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="product{{i}}-{{j}}">product</label>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="row col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success mr-1" type="submit" [disabled]="!menuForm.valid">{{buttonSubmitLabel}}</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And here is my form initialisation in TS :

```js
export class MenuEditComponent implements OnInit {

  menuForm: FormGroup;
  menu: MenuModel;
  categories: CategoryModel[];
...

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private productService: ProductService,
              private menuService: MenuService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getCategories().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.categories = result;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.categories = [];
      });
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.menuForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]),
      description: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(255)),
      price: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
      courses: new FormArray([
        this.initCourse(),
      ])
    });
  }

  initCourse() {
    return new FormGroup({
      courseName: new FormControl(''),
      products: new FormArray([
        this.initProduct()
      ])
    });
  }

  initProduct() {
    return new FormGroup({
      product: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  getCourses(form) {
    return form.controls.courses.controls;
  }

  getProducts(form) {
    return form.controls.products.controls;
  }

  onAddCourse() {
    const control = this.menuForm.get('courses') as FormArray;
    control.push(this.initCourse());
  }

  onLoadProducts(i: number) {
    console.log(this.menuForm.controls.courses);
    const courseControl = this.menuForm.get('courses') as FormArray;
    const course = courseControl.at(i).get('courseName').value;
    console.log(course);
    const products: ProductModel[] = this.mapProducts.get(course);
    console.log(products);
    const productControl = this.menuForm.get('courses').get[i].get('products') as FormArray;

  onSubmit(menuForm: FormGroup) {
    ...
  }

...
}
```

If i leave the backend like that, i have an error :

```
Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined at MenuEditComponent.getProducts
```

So my 'products' FormArray is not initialized.
If i do :

```js
  getProducts(form) {
    return form.controls.products?.controls;
  }
```

i don't have the error anymore, but i can't access the products formControls.
If i try :

```js
  onLoadProducts(i: number) {
    const courseControl = this.menuForm.get('courses') as FormArray;
    const course = courseControl.at(i).get('courseName').value;
    const products: ProductModel[] = this.mapProducts.get(course);
    const productControl = this.menuForm.get('courses').get[i].get('products') as FormArray;
    //On the last line i get a 'Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'
...
}
```

What am i doing wrong ? Why my 'products' FormArray is not initialized ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: The code that you have written does not make sense in few respectes. Why are you binding `formControlName='courseName'` to the `select` list? it means when you change the option the name of the course will be updated in the course sub form. Secondly this line `let course of courses` means what? Are not your adding courses using the top form? or is the source of courses here different? Can you put all your code on stackblitz.com I think there a few logical issues with this code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are probably right, i don't feel comfortable with angular yet, i'm just starting using it. and Reactive Form are a little blurry to me. I will try to create a stackblitz, i never used it before. To answer your questions, i'm retrieving a list of courses from an api, these categories will populate the select input, and when we select one of the course, it will fetch from the same api the list of products from this course name. I will try to create that on stackblitz straight. Thanks for your time !

Comment: Here is the stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzh3dh I will update my post to describe the problems that i encounter now !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken a look at your stackblitz and I have modified it and made it working. You don't need to bind the formControlName with your products because you are not setting them from the frontend UI rather you are just selecting them. I have added a field named `added` in the class `ProductModel` and then I have just implemented the `change` event for the checkboxes to mark it true or false.

Also you can see how I am setting the value for the product. When you hit the `Load Products` button you are adding empty `FormGroup` but you should also set the `product` control inside it with product data. You can see that in the code how i am doing it inside the LoadProducts method

After that you can see in the loop for the products how i am getting the product field. The loop is actually giving us FormGroup we have to get product field value from it

Here is the stackblitz that is doing the job.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ohwv1v

Particular you can note this part

```
if (this.productsByCategory) {
  this.productsByCategory.forEach(
  (product) => {
    const productForm: FormGroup = this.initProduct();
    productForm.controls.product.setValue(product);
      control.push(productForm);
    });
}
```

After creating the productFormGroup you should also set the product in it. like `productForm.controls.product.setValue(product);`

And then in the frontend you can see

```
<div *ngFor="let p of getProducts(course); let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product{{i}}-{{j}}" [value]="p.value.product.added" (change)="p.value.product.added = !p.value.product.added"/>
  <label  for="product{{i}}-{{j}}">{{p.value.product.name}}</label>
</div>
```

you should have the value bind to the added attribute of the product and the name should be shown inside label from the product object too.

Hopefully this will help you proceed further.

> And the second problem is that the labels of my checkboxes are not independent. If i add a new 'course' and that i select some products, the labels of all checkboxes in other courses are changed too.

The above issue is resolved

> I don't know how to be able to retrieve something like:

Rather than `productName: true/false` you have whole product object available and the `added` field will mark whether its `checked/unchecked`

Comment: It's amazing that you spend so much time on it and give me a full proper solution ! I will take a deep look at it tomorrow, cause it really killed me today ! But i saw that it works perfectly ! I really don't know how to thank you ! It's just perfect ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

courses is array of formGroup and inside that formGroup products is another formArray so you have to pass single course formGroup to getProducts method.

**component.html**

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="courses">
  <div *ngFor="let course of getCourses(menuForm); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="...">
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="courseName">
        [value]="course"
        <option *ngFor="let course of courses">{{ course.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" class="mt-2 btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="onLoadProducts(i)">
        Load Products
      </button>
      <div class="row" formArrayName="products">
        <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let product of getProducts(course); let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="product{{ i }}-{{ j }}" formControlName="product" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="product{{ i }}-{{ j }}">product</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then use get method in FormGroup to get a child control.

**component.ts**

```
getCourses(form) {
    return form.get('courses').controls;
}

getProducts(form) {
    return form.get('products').controls;
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e6h1fj)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but i'm getting other problems that i don't know how to deal with. The products are displayed, but i don't manage to retrieve the value properly, and how to display the label dynamically on each course separately. I will probably post a new question on Stack Overflow ! Thanks !

Comment: Where do you want to access products value inside onLoadProducts method?

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing it the right way. I retrieve a list of products by category (which is my 'course') from an api, and i want to be able to select some of them. With your solution, i manage to display the list of products, but one of my problem is that if i select items,  i get in output `{...courses": [{"courseName": "Entrée","products": [{"product": true},{"product": false}...]}`, so i can't identify which product is selected and which is not. I would like to have in the products array the name of my product as a key.I don't know if i should edit my post or create a new one !

Comment: You mean inside onLoadProducts you want to get selected courses value?

Comment: That i managed to do, my problem now is to use and retrieve the correct values from the product checboxes. I have made a stackblitz here http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzh3dh and i updated my posts to try to make it more clear !

Comment: Can you check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-carnzo

Comment: Great ! It's super ! I just need to find out how to display the checkbox label independently of my lodPrpduct() method now ! Thanks a lot it's really really helpful !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215519/discussion-between-chellappan--and-alain-duguine).